# .htaccess not able to redirect url

Tags: .htaccess

We have a project which are developed on open cart. We have some URLs that if user hits those URLs then system will redirect users to another specified URL. To do this, We have made some changes in .htaccess file.

Here is my original .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]  

RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now to redirect we have added following lines given below:

```
Redirect 302 http://www.covermale.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=23 http://www.covermale.com/obviously
```

But our system not able to redirect to http://mensuas.veldev.com/obviously.
Can anyone please tell us, Is something wrong in above rule?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=23$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.covermale.com/obviously? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove the space from flags: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /obviously? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution also not able to redirect the url

Comment: Please note, that the [L] flag can only be set once (last rule)

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htacces like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{query_STRING} route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=23 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /obviously? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]  

RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: there's no mention of the domain "covermale.com" in your answer, so I doubt this will work

Comment: in first redirect rule there is no need to mention domain name if sources and target URLs are for same domain

Comment: ok that's actually a good point, I got a similar question here, but in my case domains are different so not sure how to apply your solution , do you think you could give it a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423283/302-redirect-url-with-parameters