# 302 redirect url with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

In htaccess file the following works

```
redirect 302 /old.php http://somesite.com/new.php
```

but following fails

```
redirect 302 /old.php?this=that http://somesite.com/new.php
```

I think it's because the second version contains a query string. How can we redirect URLs like that?

Please note the destination URL format is different so it cannot be an automated rule, so I need to write the custom URLs that users will be redirected to.

I found a similar question with replies here, but the proposed solutions do not work:

[.htaccess not able to redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398818/htaccess-not-able-to-redirect-url)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as topmost rule in site root .htaccess of old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)this=that(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^old\.php$ http://somesite.com/new.php? [R=301,L]
```